# Realm.io : Trouble with HTTPS proxy with letsencrypt

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to enable https proxy for Realm object server.

I keep getting errors like this when trying to use the Android sample app.

https://gist.github.com/jtexp/fdc43315a9e8c5dd487f4880bb48c7b4

I setup with Rhel 7.3 using letsencrypt with built in https proxy and then i just tried the Ubuntu AMI with built in https and nginx proxy.  My certs work fine on apache/nginx so I'm curious what's goin on here.

Is there more I need to change in the app other than the URLs?

Comment: In the logs there's a line: `Connection[1]: Connecting to endpoint '54.172.20.45:9443' (1/1)` It seems you're connecting to the IP address for the server. Why? You should configure a host name (like realm.mydomain.com) and associate the certificate with that hostname. That's the way the SSL certificate validation will result in a successful request.

Comment: @Orlando I used a hostname AUTH_URL = "https://realm.uzsy.download:9443/auth" and REALM_URL = "realms://realm.uzsy.download:9443/~/realmtasks";  I saw that line in the log too and tried to trace it through the docs https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/SyncUser.html#loginAsync-io.realm.SyncCredentials-java.lang.String-io.realm.SyncUser.Callback-   https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/SyncConfiguration.Builder.html but I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: While I trying to open your URL `realm.uzsy.download:9443/auth` the server responds with `Cannot GET /auth`. Also, in a tutorial from Realm (https://realm.io/docs/tutorials/realmtasks/) I can see a URL in the form `realm://127.0.0.1:9080/~/realmtasks`. Are you sure you're putting the URL in the right way? The route `/auth` does not exist.

Comment: Yeah I'm not running realm-object-server right now that's why the route doesn't work. The documentation is bad here, but to specify a realm with tls you use realms. It was in the github tracker tucked somewhere.

Comment: here is the issue tracker where it describes realms:// https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/100

Comment: Don't know if this issue is still active, but there seems to be a problem with your certificate/hostname. `SSL handshake failed: certificate verify failed`. Also, as @user3749364 indicated, you need to ensure that you connect to `realms://`, otherwise the client won't know that it's supposed to create a TLS connection.

Comment: @teotwaki Yeah user37.. is me. :)  The problem is I don't know why the cert verify failed.  It works on Apache and Nginx through the browser.  Just not working on Realm server/client.  Let me know if you can provide some more direct support.  I can go through the setup again and post a github issue if needed.

Comment: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/android-doesnt-trust-the-certificate/16498/17